# Parsing a JSON string to array, not object

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, object

I've got a PHP array and echo that into javascript with json encode, i need to do it this way because it's going to be very dynamic. This is the code it echo's:

```
{"notempty":true}
```

And i use this to, convert it to javascript:

```
var myarray = eval('(' + json + ')');
```

For some reason it creates an object instead of an array and for that reason i cant use .length or a for loop.

Does someone know what im doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: In JS enumerated array (or what would be an enumerated array in PHP) behaves like object

Comment: The reason is that you cannot have associative arrays in JavaScript. Objects are the closest match.

Comment: Do not use eval. Use a JSON parse method like jQuery's http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON or use Douglas Crockford's parseJSON method. See https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js (download json2.js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to treat an `Object` like an `Array`, and an `Object` is not an `Array`, it is an `Object`.

Any time you see `{}` in JSON, that means "What is contained within these hallowed brackets is a dynamic object". When you see `[]`, that means "Behold! I am an Array" (there are notable exceptions to this one: jQuery does some special work with to make itself look like an array).

So, in order to iterate through an `Object`, you'll want to use `for... in`.

```
// eval BAD unless you know your input has been sanitized!.
var myObj = JSON.parse('{"notempty":true}');
// personally, I use it in for... in loops. It clarifies that this is a string
// you may want to use hasOwnProperty here as sometimes other "keys" are inserted
for( var it in myObj ) console.log( "myObj["+it+"] = " + myObj[it] );
```

Comment: Don't forget to use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) when iterating over an objects properties: `for (var it in myObj) if(myObj.hasOwnProperty(it)) {do something}`

Comment: Thank you very much, telling me the way to loop through an object totally solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is an object, which contains one attribute named `notempty`. If you want an array, it'd have to be

```
[{"notempty":true}]
```

which is an array with a single element at index 0, which is an object with the single attribute 'notempty';.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you use encode an assoc array in php, it will become a js object when you decode. In order to have it be an array, you need to make it an array in php:

PHP:

```
$arr = "['notempty','notempty2','notempty3']";
```

Otherwise, you should convert it to an array in JS, but that seems to me a waste since looping through the object in javascript is so much easier:

Javascript:

```
var arr = new Array();
for(var i in obj) arr[i] = obj[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to parse it into an array like this:

```
var p = [];
$.each(jsonData, function (key, val) {
    p.push([val.propertyOne, val.propertyTwo]);
});
```

I am presuming of course that you want to parse JSON, not an array or any other string.